# How to redirect port 80 and 8080 to 443 using nginx for a Jenkins server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redirect, jenkins

I am try to redirect anything going to port 80 and 8080 to 443 (https) using nginx. This is for a Jenkins server. I am using ubuntu. This is the nginx config I have at the moment:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name jenkins.mydomain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header    Host      $host;
    proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 https://jenkins.mydomain.com;
  }

  return 301 https://jenkins.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name jenkins.mydomain.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /path/to/wildcard.mydomain.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/wildcard.mydomain.com.key;

  location / {
    add_header Cache-Control private;
    expires epoch;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;

    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout  90s;
    proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 https://jenkins.mydomain.com;
  }
}
```

As you can see I tried adding the proxy related headers to the port 80 server block but that is not working. When I go to http://jenkins.mydomain.com or http://jenkins.mydomain.com:8080 it does not redirect to https://jenkins.mydomain.com. How do I redirect anything going to port 80 and 8080 to 443?

Answer (score 3):

I am using this config, maybe from any documentation page and it is working for years without any problem. It should be probably better but for my internal usage is it enough.

```
upstream jenkins {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server { 
        listen 80; 
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name XXXX fail_timeout=0;
        return 301 https://XXXXX$request_uri; 
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl on; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/XXXX.cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/XXXX.key.pem;

    server_name XXXXX;

    location / { 

      proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://jenkins;
      proxy_redirect http:// https://;
      add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    }   
}
```